# how does ntfs implement raid 0

Tags: raid, ntfs

My understanding was that Windows can implement something like RAID 0 programmaticaly, that is, if you don't have a physical RAID controller, you can still make two hard drives to appear as one.

How does NTFS address blocks on the other hard drive in this case? Is it a specific driver that does the mapping? Or is there some different way the location of the clusters on the other hard drive are addressed in MFT (master file table)?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

Software RAID is usually implemented by a [file-system filter driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx).

If you're just interested more in what NTFS can do, http://www.ntfs.com/ is a nice place to start.

Comment: Software RAID is usually implemented by a block driver below the filesystem, not a filter driver above it.

Comment: Aren't low level filter drivers below the filesystem?

Comment: A file system filter driver filters filesystem requests (like 'open file', 'remove directory', and so on). The RAID is implemented more like a block device filter, handling the requests issued *by* the filesystem (like 'read block', 'write block'). When the filesystem goes to write a block, a mirroring RAID driver will write the block to both drives. When the filesystem goes to read a block, the mirroring RAID driver will try to read the block from one drive and if it fails, the other. There are a few reasons you can't do it the other way. (How would 'chkdsk' work?)

Comment: Yes, of course it must work this way; I just understood lower-level filter drivers to be under the function driver so it would be talking blocks to the underlying device via block IOCTLs from the filesystem. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes, now you've got it. As your link says, "A file system filter driver intercepts requests targeted at a file system or another file system filter driver." That's *not* how RAID works. It acts on requests targeted at a block device driver, not requests targeted at a file system or file system filter driver. Correct concept, wrong level. (One more down.)

Comment: Ah, I see now - yes, the link only talks about upper level drivers. It seems that the terms upper-level / lower-level might not even be used anymore.